# Class 'PDO' not found

Tags: zend-framework, pdo

I have this error when upload the website created in Zend Framework

Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /library/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 32

although I have this code in php.ini

```
extension=pdo.so 
extension=pdo_sqlite.so 
extension=sqlite.so 
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

what I can do to solve this problem ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What version of PHP does your host run? http://php.net/pdo

Comment: Now I use PHP version 5.3.10 and it's work, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class 'PDO' not found related to the version of PHP

you should use PHP version 5.3.x and it will work